# Reading multilevel XML with PHP (SimpleXML)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm struggling with PHP code that would read following XML file:

```
<putovanja agencija="Kompas Zagreb d.d.">
  <putovanje url="http://www.kompas.hr/Packages/Package.aspx?idPackage=3151" tip="Krstarenja Jadranom" destinacija="Krstarenja" naziv="Mini Krstarenje Jadranom Zadar-Opatija (5 noći, jedan smjer) " id="3151" polazak="Zadar (Krstarenje)">
    <ukrcaji>
      <ukrcaj>Zadar</ukrcaj>
    </ukrcaji>
    <datumiIcijene>
      <data od="28.08.2017" do="02.09.2017" cijena="3695"/>
      <data od="04.09.2017" do="09.09.2017" cijena="3360"/>
      <data od="11.09.2017" do="16.09.2017" cijena="3360"/>
    </datumiIcijene>
  </putovanje>
  <putovanje url="http://www.kompas.hr/Packages/Package.aspx?idPackage=3151" tip="Odmor" destinacija="Krstarenja" naziv="Mini Krstarenje Jadranom Zadar-Opatija (5 noći, jedan smjer) " id="3151" polazak="Zadar (Krstarenje)">
    <ukrcaji>
      <ukrcaj>Zadar</ukrcaj>
    </ukrcaji>
    <datumiIcijene>
      <data od="28.08.2017" do="02.09.2017" cijena="3695"/>
      <data od="04.09.2017" do="09.09.2017" cijena="3360"/>
    </datumiIcijene>
  </putovanje>
</putovanja>
```

I found sample online, more specifically on w3schools(https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp), I understand my XML is more complex, but I can't even get the URL of first "CHILD". I think loop goes trough right child as it write BREAK twice in the output. Does anyone have any clue where I made a mistake?

I'm really sorry if my question is stupid, I'm still learning how to code.

Thanks for all the help and wish you all a nice day :D

oh and my current code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("putovanja.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $putovanja) {
    echo $putovanja->putovanje['url'];
    echo "Break <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a silly question, would you consider switching to a JSON string? It is much simpler to work with. You can use a single php function to get an assoc array which is simple to traverse. If that is unacceptable for your project, then ignore this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: You mean to use json instead of XML? It has to be XML, can't effect source file.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know the scope of your project. If you were just trying to create a configuration file, or if you must read existing source files.

Comment: You're very nearly there Laurent. Note that the `$xml` variable represents the `<putovanja>` element. You're looping over its children (the `<putovanje>` elements), which is good. Then you mistakenly try to access a `<putovanje>` child element of each, which doesn't exist. If you renamed `$putovanja` to `$putovanje`, then did `echo $putovanje['url'];` you'd be there.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should specify that better, thanks for your comment

Comment: @salathe thanks for your answer I will try with changed variable, if I understood right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to access the URLs:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("putovanja.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->putovanje as $p) {
    echo $p->attributes()->url;
    echo "\n";
}
```

You don't need `children()` and you'll find `attributes()` useful

To access more elements then here is an example:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("putovanja.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->putovanje as $p) {
    echo $p->attributes()->url;
    echo "\n";
    echo $p->ukrcaji->ukrcaj;    
    echo "\n";    
    echo $p->datumiIcijene->data[0]->attributes()->od;           
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

If you add `print_r($p);` within the loop then you'll see the data structure and be able to follow my example and access the other elements you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and then I guess I can go one level deeper if I just make another loop in current loop?

Comment: Yes, what specifically do you want to extract from the XML file? Let me know and I can update my answer

Comment: Honestly, everything, the assignment wants all the data to be in the table. So all attributes, "ukrcaj" and attributes of "datumiIcijene"/DATA.

Comment: OK, answer updated. This should help to get you started

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot :) I most certainly owe you a beer

Comment: Why do you suggest using `attributes()` here? Unless there are namespaces involved, `$p->attributes()->url` is completely identical to `$p['url']`, and `$p->datumiIcijene->data[0]->attributes()->od` is identical to `$p->datumiIcijene->data[0]['od']` or even `$p->datumiIcijene->data['od']`.